# UIButton's action automatically takes a delay to respond

Tags: swift, uibutton, action, delay

I've created an outlet and an action for it through storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pillButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func pillPressed(_ sender: Any) { ...
```

When I press the button, its action fires right away. However, if I press it again in 5 seconds, it does not respond. It's like it has an internal delay to "sleep" after it's clicked. How do I disable it?

I know that it isn't responding because I've put this break point.

[image: break point set]

Comment: There shouldn't, but what do you do in `pillPressed()` exactly? Are you doing something block the mainthread?

Comment: Try moving the "pill image" logic into your model, away from the view controller: rather than examining the content of button's background image, which may be very time-consuming, try keeping the state in the model that indicates whether or not pill image is displayed as the background of `pillButton`. Once the timing of this check is reduced, I expect the performance problem to be fixed.

Comment: thanks guys u are correct... the internal code if the action had a UIAnimate which was blocking the main code, case solved

Answer (score 0):

Internal code if the action had a UIAnimate which was blocking the main thread